# UIScrollView or UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

Iam working on app for iOS5.
I would like to have a big picture in a small frame, at one time in this frame would be shown only part of the image. When user swipe right or left the image would shift to its second half. I would like to ask you what should I use, UIScrollView or UIPageViewController?? Or should I use anything else?? 
Thanks for all the tips

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using a `UIScrollView` with its `pagingEnabled` property set to `YES`.

This will make it snap to multiplies of its view bounds. So if your view is 640 wide, and your image is 1280 wide, it will snap between the first half and second half.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the image to slide to the left or right, then use `UIScrollView` (perhaps with `pagingEnabled` set to `YES`).  If you want a page-turn effect, use `UIPageViewController`.